# iphone, addSubview show view too high up, how do I move to down?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm using addSubView twice in my app and both times it adds the view too high up the view, its off the screen at the top. See below... I have load the views like this as I nothing else works, cause me problems.

I just don't understand why they are showing off the screen?

What do I need to do to fix this ?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
[window addSubview:rootController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
lvc = [[GettingStartedViewController alloc] 
            initWithNibName:@"GettingStartedView" bundle:nil];
[window addSubview:lvc.view];       
return YES;
}
```

And in my GettingStartedView ...

```
- (IBAction) showHelp:(id)inSender {    
theController = [[HelpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HelpView" 
                    bundle:nil onPage:HelpPageGettingStarted];
[self.view addSubview:theController.view];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the location:

```
rootController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460);
```

Comment: rootController in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ?

Comment: Um, that's not even a complete sentence. Please be more explicit and descriptive, I have no idea what you are trying to ask me :-)

Comment: Great answer! Solved my problem also!

Answer (score 1):

Check the `wantsFullScreenLayout` property of your root view controller, make sure it's *not* set.

Comment: rootController in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ?

Comment: You can set it there, or just un-check the checkbox in your .xib file.