# Views moving for no reason

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiview, subview

Bit of a strange one. So I had my iPhone app navigating between various screens perfectly fine and the decided to add animations between all the pages. Once added in, the animations themselves all worked fine, but as soon as I move from the home page, the view seems to shift up inside the window a small distance. After that, whichever page I move to, the view stays shifted slightly up. That is until I navigate to one of my pages which auto rotates to accommodate for videos. When on this page, the view fits the screen fine, and when I navigate off, the view flips back to portrait and the view is then perfectly fine for all of the other screens again, no shifting. All of this happened after I added the animation code for the screens but I can't see why that would have affected this at all unless I accidentally changed something else.

The following is the code I have put in to use with animations:

```
WhatIsCTTView *whatIsCTTView = [[WhatIsCTTView alloc] initWithNibName:@"WhatIsCTTView" bundle:nil];
UIView *currentView = self.view;
UIView *theWindow = [currentView superview];
UIView *newView = whatIsCTTView.view; 
[currentView removeFromSuperview];
[theWindow addSubview:newView];
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.5];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[[theWindow layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToCTTView"];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks,

Matt

EDIT:

I found out how to fix this problem, just add the line

"newView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460);"

after you add a new subview to the screen to make sure it is placed in the right position. See this SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952483/iphone-addsubview-show-view-too-high-up-how-do-i-move-to-down) for where I got my answer.

Matt

Comment: Why don't you simply use UINavigationController if you want to push new views from right to left?

Comment: Because I don't know how to use them. How would you go about doing that? You should probably also know that I do have quite a lot of different views that would need navigating. Is it just a matter of extending the UINavigationController class in the header file?
But do you know if that would sort out whatever is wrong with my views at the moment?